# What does the projection of test image into the eigenface space, exactly mean?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, eigenvector

In the face recognition using [eigenfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface) technique, what does the projection of test image (unknown face image) into the eigenface space, exactly mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means representing test image as a weighted sum of eigenfaces.

To calculate the projection:  multiply the test image by each eigenface, pixel-by-pixel, and sum the result pixels to get the coefficient for that eigenface.  The "projection onto eigenface space" is the list of these coefficients.

To reconstitute the test image from its eigenface space projection, multiply each eigenface by its coefficient and then just add all the resulting images together.

Note that the above procedures assume that your eigenface vectors have been normalized to unit length.